# Implementing Multi Select in GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-camera

I need to select multiple images inside the `GridView` and add share and delete button to the `Gridview`.

My `ImageAdapter` class:

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageView;
        CheckableLayout checkableLayout;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(activity);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            checkableLayout = new CheckableLayout(activity);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
        } else {
            checkableLayout = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
            imageView = (ImageView) checkableLayout.getChildAt(0);
        }

        bitmap = decodeFile(getItem(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        return imageView;

    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        int position;

        public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ImageDisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", getPosition(position));
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public class CheckableLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {

        private boolean mChecked;

        public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            setBackgroundDrawable(checked ? getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue) : null);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChecked() {
            return mChecked;
        }

        @Override
        public void toggle() {
            setChecked(!mChecked);
        }
    }

    public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            int selectCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
            switch (selectCount) {
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Select Items");
            mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error when I try to open Gridview.

My Logcat details

> 02-10 21:10:46.965  21658-21658/com.android.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.android.example, PID: 21658
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.android.example.GridViewActivity$CheckableLayout
>               at com.android.example.GridViewActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(GridViewActivity.java:224)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
>               at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1044)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to
>   com.android.example.GridViewActivity$CheckableLayout

Because you are returning `ImageView` from `getView` but trying to convert it to `CheckableLayout` in this line:

```
checkableLayout = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
```

return `checkableLayout` from `getView()` method :

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, 
                            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ImageView imageView;
            CheckableLayout checkableLayout;

            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(activity); 
                // your code here ... 
                // add ImageView to checkableLayout
                checkableLayout.addView(imageView); 

            } else 
               checkableLayout = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
               imageView = (ImageView) checkableLayout.getChildAt(0);
               // your code here ... 
              return checkableLayout;

   }
```

Comment: Now i'm not getting an error. But i'm not able to select multiple items inside grid view. Can you provide a right example to implement it. Like android gallery does.

Comment: @LikithTs: still facing same issue or this answer help you in fixing issue as posted in question?

Comment: Instead of using Gridview. I have implement the recyclerView for displaying gridview images. But I dint find a better example to implement muti touch inside the recyclerView.

Comment: @LikithTs: ok good but you have posted question regarding getting exception `ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to` so this answer fixed current exception or not if fixed then accept it other wise let me know i will delete it because answer is not useful

Comment: Should I have to post a new Question or shall I edit my question for RecyclerView.

Comment: Yeah this fixed the error. Any idea in implementing multiselect in recyclerView?

Comment: @LikithTs: Always post new question for any issue instead of editing current question because like in current question i have answers your question according to  `ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast` problem so if you change this question description and code and some one search on google for "Implementing Multi Select in GridView android" line then he will get question and answer text's mismatch.Thanks

Comment: Will Post a new question and give you a link.

Answer (score 2):

You should return `convertView` from `getView` method.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // code here

    convertview.addView(checkableLayout);
    return convertView;

}
```